# Inserting something at a particular line in a text file using PHP

Tags: php, file-io

I have a file called config.php, I want it to remain exactly as is, however on Line # 4 there is a line saying:

```
$config['url'] = '...could be anything here';
```

I'd like to only replace the contents of line # 4 with my own url provided for `$config['ur']`, is there a way to do this in PHP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you know the exact line number, probably the most accurate way to do this is to use file(), which returns an array of lines:

```
$contents = file('config.php');
$contents[3] = '$config[\'url\'] = "whateva"'."\n";
$outfile = fopen('config.php','w');
fwrite($outfile,implode('',$contents));
fclose($outfile);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$myline = "my confg line";

$file = "config.php";

$contents = file($file);
$contents[3] = $myLine;
$file = implode("\n", $contents);
```

Answer (score 1):

Either create another config (myconfig.php). Include the original and overwrite the option. include myconfig.php instead of the original one.

OR

Go to where config is included (you did use a single place for all your includes right?) and set the config option there.

```
   include "config.php"
   $config['url'] = "my_leet_urlz";
```

Answer (score 0):

you could read the file, use str_replace or preg_replace on the appropriate strings, then write the file back to itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
$filename = "/path/to/file/filename";
$configFile = file($filename);
$configFile[3] = '$'."config['url'] = '...could be anything here';";
file_put_contents($filename  ,$configFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one $config['url'], use a  preg_replace()
http://us.php.net/preg_replace

something like:
$pattern = '\$config['url'] = "[\d\w\s]*"'
$file_contents = preg_replace($pattern, $config['url'] = "my_leet_urlz";,$file_contents);

you'll need to fix the pattern as I'm new at regex and I know that's not right.